# Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect remotely to an SQL Server Express instance hosted on an Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: sql-server, azure, remote-access, ports

## Initial Attempt

I have an Azure VM with Windows Server 2012, on which I just installed SQL Server 2012 Express Database Engine component. Then, I followed the instructions [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/install-sql-server/#SSMS) to connect remotely with SQL Server Management Studio.

> 1. Create a TCP endpoint for the virtual machine
> 2. Open TCP ports in the Windows firewall
> 3. Configure SQL Server to listen on the TCP protocol
> 4. Configure SQL Server for mixed mode authentication
> 5. Create SQL Server authentication logins
> 6. Determine the DNS name of the virtual machine
> 7. Connect to the Database Engine from another computer

After step seven I received the following error:

> A network related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

What else do I need to configure before connecting remotely?

## Troubleshooting

I have been following the troubleshooting instructions [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx). Each blockquote below is a step described that that link.

> Confirm the instance of the SQL Server Database Engine is installed
>   and running.

Done. We installed SQL Server Express, and it is running as a named instance called SQLEXPRESS.

> If you are attempting to connect to a named instance, make sure the
>   SQL Server Browser service is running.

Done. We followed the steps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to turn on the SQL Server Browser service.

> Get the IP Address of the computer.

Done. We will use these later for testing connectivity and maybe for setting up a static port for SQLEXPRESS.

10.241.62.155

fe80::45c:8c29:e19f:f78b%15

> Get the TCP port number used by SQL Server.

Done. The [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=29062) server logs showed that the server was listening on port 49169.

> Enable Protocols

Done. We had already enabled TCP/IP in the configuration manager, but we restarted the SQL Server Service just in case.

> Testing TCP/IP Connectivity

Done. We used [tcping.exe](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php) to test connectivity (cmd ping doesn't work quickly with Azure.) We were able to connect to port 80.

- tcping.exe buddha.cloudapp.net > successful
- tcping.exe buddha.cloudapp.net 80 > successful

> Testing a Local Connection

Done. We used [sqlcmd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) from the command prompt and were able to connect locally via TCP with a username and password.

- sqlcmd -S Buddha\SQLEXPRESS (success via shared memory protocol)
- sqlcmd -S tcp:Buddha\SQLEXPRESS (success via TCP)
- sqlcmd -S tcp:Buddha\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P  (success via TCP with username)
- sqlcmd -S tcp:10.241.62.155\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P  (success with internal IP)

> Opening a Port in the Firewall

We opened the port on which we SQLEXPRESS listens. The server logs (above) showed that SQLEXPRESS was listening on port 49169, but this is just one of many dynamic ports, and we wanted to set up the static port 1435.

- Use WF.msc to create an inbound TCP rule for port 1435.
- Use Azure Management Portal to create a TCP endpoint for port 1435.

The troubleshooting instructions also say:

> If you are connecting to a **named instance** or a port other than TCP
>   port 1433, you must also open the **UDP port 1434** for the SQL Server
>   Browser service.

Since we are connecting SQLEXPRESS (a named instance), we needed to open port 1434 for UDP.

- Use WF.msc to create an inbound **UCP** rule for port 1434.
- Use Azure Management Portal to create a **UDP** endpoint for port 1434

Further research about connecting to named instances revealed dynamic port issues. The reason why we are using port 1435 (static) instead of port 49169 (one of many effective options.)

> Instances of SQL Server Express, SQL Server Compact, and named
>   instances of the Database Engine use dynamic ports. To configure these
>   instances to use a specific port, see [Configure a Server to Listen on
>   a Specific TCP Port (SQL Server Configuration Manager).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx) and
>   [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2009/07/17/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-listen-on-different-ports-on-different-ip-addresses.aspx).

Done. We went to SQL Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLEXPRESS > TCP/IP, we did the following.

Protocol Tab > Listen All > NO.

IP Addresses Tab > for each listed address

- Enabled > Yes
- TCP Dynamic Ports > Blank (delete the zero)
- TCP Port > 1435 (or your choice)

After restarting the SQLEXPRESS service, we again looked in the SQL Server Management Studio logs, and found that the Server is Listening on port 1435!!! Hooray!

> Testing the Connection

Done. We opened SQL Server Management Studio on our local (non-Azure) computer and connected.

- buddha.cloudapp.net,1435 OR buddha.cloudapp.net\SQLEXPRESS
- sa
- password

Success.

Comment: Wow, incredible job of listing all the steps and attempts.

Comment: You just saved me a ton of time! The key for me was the very end: Protocol Tab > Listen All > NO. I didn't have to change the IP from 1433, but I did delete the 0 from Dynamic Ports for good measure. I assume my issues stemmed from all of those other listed protocols listening. Good job!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are the three web pages on which we found the answer. The most difficult part was setting up static ports for SQLEXPRESS.

[Provisioning a SQL Server Virtual Machine on Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/install-sql-server/). These initial instructions provided 25% of the answer.

[How to Troubleshoot Connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx). Reading this carefully provided another 50% of the answer.

[How to configure SQL server to listen on different ports on different IP addresses?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2009/07/17/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-listen-on-different-ports-on-different-ip-addresses.aspx). This enabled setting up static ports for named instances (eg SQLEXPRESS.) It took us the final 25% of the way to the answer.

Answer (score 18):

The fact that you're getting an error from the Names Pipes Provider tells us that you're not using the TCP/IP protocol when you're trying to establish the connection. Try adding the "tcp" prefix and specifying the port number:

```
tcp:name.cloudapp.net,1433
```

Comment: Hi Paul, There is still an error but now it's from TCP Provider not Named Pipes Provider. – Shaun Luttin 7 mins ago

Comment: Sorry, based on a quick read of your question, I thought you had already configured your server to listen on static port 1433.

Answer (score 4):

I too struggled with something similar. My guess is your actual problem is connecting to a SQL Express instance running on a different machine. The steps to do this can be summarized as follows:

1. Ensure SQL Express is configured for SQL Authentication as well as Windows Authentication (the default). You do this via SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) Server Properties/Security
2. In SSMS create a new login called "sqlUser", say, with a suitable password, "sql", say. Ensure this new login is set for SQL Authentication, not Windows Authentication. SSMS Server Security/Logins/Properties/General. Also ensure "Enforce password policy" is unchecked
3. Under Properties/Server Roles ensure this new user has the "sysadmin" role
4. In SQL Server Configuration Manager SSCM (search for SQLServerManagerxx.msc file in Windows\SysWOW64 if you can't find SSCM) under SQL Server Network Configuration/Protocols for SQLExpress make sure TCP/IP is enabled. You can disable Named Pipes if you want
5. Right-click protocol TCP/IP and on the IPAddresses tab, ensure every one of the IP addresses is set to Enabled Yes, and TCP Port 1433 (this is the default port for SQL Server)
6. In Windows Firewall (WF.msc) create two new Inbound Rules - one for SQL Server and another for SQL Browser Service. For SQL Server you need to open TCP Port 1433 (if you are using the default port for SQL Server) **and very importantly for the SQL Browser Service you need to open UDP Port 1434**. Name these two rules suitably in your firewall
7. Stop and restart the SQL Server Service using either SSCM or the Services.msc snap-in
8. In the Services.msc snap-in make sure SQL Browser Service Startup Type is Automatic and then start this service

At this point you should be able to connect remotely, using SQL Authentication, user "sqlUser" password "sql" to the SQL Express instance configured as above. A final tip and easy way to check this out is to create an empty text file with the .UDL extension, say "Test.UDL" on your desktop. Double-clicking to edit this file invokes the Microsoft Data Link Properties dialog with which you can quickly test your remote SQL connection

Comment: God-like answer. In step 5 only thing I did was setting 1433 at IPAll -> TCP Port and it worked too.