# Unable to connect from local to SQL Server in Virtual Machine on Windows Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to connect from a local SQL Server Management Studio to a SQL Server hosted in a VM on Azure. 
I followed all the instructions from 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/install-sql-server/ and created the necessary endpoints:

[image]

Somehow, I can't connect to the SQL Server, getting this error

---

```
Cannot connect to xxx.cloudapp.net.
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection
to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance      
name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.  
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)  
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)


The network path was not found
```

---

I already tried to temporary disable the windows firewall on the vm - without success. Any suggestions?

Comment: any updates on this one? I'm getting the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, this troubleshot helped me getting close to the solution:

[Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect remotely to an SQL Server Express instance hosted on an Azure Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956465/use-sql-server-management-studio-to-connect-remotely-to-an-sql-server-express-in)

Summing up, what i did, i don't know if all these steps are necessary, so you should test after each one:

1) In SQL Server configuration manager enable Named Pipes in protocols

2) In the VM add a windows firewall inbound rule for sql server port (in my case the default 1433, in yours it seems to be 1435, make sure it's 1435 in sql server configuration)

3) Make Sure you are using a sql server authentication login (not a windows authentication) if you don't have one create it locally in the VM>MSSMS

4) Make Sure the SQL server is configured for mixed authentication (http://www.katieandemil.com/microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-for-user)

5) Make sure sql server browser is running

Hope this helps :)