# error connect to remote SQL Server Express 2012 windows 10 c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, networking, connection-string

i have SQL server express 2012 installed on windows 10 64 bit, the connection from same computer worked fine,  problem when i connect from another computer on same network,
i get error message:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connection
-provider TCP provider error 0 the wait operation timeout
```

i try the following things but not fix the problem:

- Enable and automaticly start SQL Browser
- Enbale TCP/IP and set port 1433 for all IP types
- Start Named inslance SQLExpress2012 autmaticaly as Build-in : Network service
- connect without user and password with IntegratedSecurity=true
- The database is using mixed-mode authentication
- add an exception in the firewall for port 1433
- enable named pipe
- allow remote connection

this is my code:

```
        public static bool TestSQLServerConnection(
            string ComputerNameOrIPAddress,
            string SQLServerInstanceName,
            string PortNumber)
        {

            try
            {
                
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder SQLServerConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                SQLServerConnectionString.DataSource = ComputerNameOrIPAddress+",+"+PortNumber+"\\"+SQLServerInstanceName;
                SQLServerConnectionString.InitialCatalog = DatabseName;
                SQLServerConnectionString.TrustServerCertificate = true;
                SQLServerConnectionString.IntegratedSecurity = true;
                
                //SQLServerConnectionString.UserID = "...";
                //SQLServerConnectionString.NetworkLibrary = "DBMSSOCN";
                //SQLServerConnectionString.Password = "...";

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SQLServerConnectionString.ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText=  "select 1";
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                con.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

when i ping the ip address or computer name of computer of SQL Server it connected and return response, means the computer is connected to network.
i search for while without any solution, please help me.Thanks

Comment: Is the browser service on  the host also running? You say that the instance is called `SQLExpress2012`; the default name for an express instance is `EXPRESS`, so I assume you've chosen to use a different name? Also, side question, why 2012? Express is free, and 2012's is pretty close to end of extended support; there's several newer versions that have full support.

Comment: SQL Browser uses 1434 also

Comment: i use sql server 2012 Express , because i have windows 32 bit and from sql server 2014 and newer it only work on win 64 bit

Comment: yes i start SQL Browser service automatically

Comment: i install SQL Server management studio on another computer and try to connect to SQL server in remote computer, it connected but i cannot see my database in database engine, and i still cannot connect to  SQL server vi my code mentioned above.

Comment: why i can connect from sql server management studio to remote sql server but i cannot see my database in database engine, and i cannot connect with my code mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

I add
SQL Browser Service UDP Port 1434 on firewall and worked fine.
[Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect remotely to an SQL Server Express instance hosted on an Azure Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956465/use-sql-server-management-studio-to-connect-remotely-to-an-sql-server-express-in)